# Improving algorithm for rotating around a 3d point on a certain axis

Tags: c#, game-engine, matrix-multiplication, opentk, rotational-matrices

I created a C# method (using the OpenTK library) that calculates the position of a point A that gets rotated at a given distance around a point B. The rotation is around the y-axis (which is "up" in my game world).

```
public static Vector3 CalculateRotationAroundPointOnAxis(Vector3 B, float distance, float 
              degrees)
{
    // First of all: convert degrees to radians
    float radians = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(degrees % 360);

    // Create a translation matrix that stores the translation from (0|0|0) to point B:
    Matrix4.CreateTranslation(ref B, out translationPointMatrix);

    // Create a rotation matrix for the rotation around y-axis:
    Matrix4.CreateRotationY(radians, out rotationMatrix);
    // Create a second translation matrix that stores the translation from point B to the rotation distance:
    Matrix4.CreateTranslation(0, 0, distance, out translationMatrix);

    // First apply the translation to point B, then rotate:
    Matrix4.Mult(ref translationMatrix, ref rotationMatrix, out tempMatrix);
    // Afterwards, apply the second translation:
    Matrix4.Mult(ref tempMatrix, ref translationPointMatrix, out finalTranslationMatrix);

    // Apply finalTranslationMatrix to Vector3 (0|0|0) and return the new position:
    Vector3.TransformPosition(ref Vector3.Zero, ref finalTranslationMatrix, out finalTranslationPoint);
    return finalTranslationPoint;
}
```

I do understand why the matrices need to be multiplied in the above order. But I think that the whole process is way too expensive! I have so many matrix operations and I think that the whole process can be sped up.

**Question:** How can I make this algorithm faster?

Comment: If your solution works, consider posting this on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead

Comment: *"But I think that the whole process is way too expensive"* - What you actually do is `translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * finalTranslationMatrix`. This are 2 matrix concatenations and this formula is typical for rotating around a pivot. That is not complicated at all and I can't see any way for optimizing this. Anyway, OpenTK provides the `*` -operator for matrix multiplications (that won't give any speed up, but it makes the code easier to read).

Comment: Faster way would be to do the multiplications your self without using matrix. you might be able to simplify a few operations by hand if you know what components are always zero.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary A rotation around an axis in 3d space is not something what should be done by "your self". See [Rotation matrix from axis and angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle).

Comment: I think what @M.kazemAkhgary was pointing out is that my rotation matrices only make use of 9 out of their 16 cells and that a Matrix4 * Matrix4 operation would result in some unneeded multiplications.

Comment: That looks scary. but since rotation axis is Y which is `(0, 1, 0)` you already have a lot of zeros in there. @Rabbid76

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Oh, you're right. I just realized that it is a rotation around the Y axis. That simplifies things a lot.

Comment: For now it is around y axis, but I will later swap the Matrix4.CreateRotationY() part with creating a matrix that holds any rotation around any axis.

Comment: In that case you might stick with matrix operations. Also read about [Instruction pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining). modern CPU is able to cram multiple instructions together and execute them faster

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. Can you please formulate an answer so I can mark this problem as solved?